# How can memory testing programs work without being a security breach?

Tags: memory, security, memory-management

I was just running a memory test on my laptop (from the manufacturer, running **as a service in Windows 10 Pro**) and it occurred to me that they claim to be able to actually test all of the memory in the system (which requires reading and writing memory).

However, in modern systems, applications never get "real" memory, they get a virtual memory image (they essentially think they have access to the whole system, but really it's a virtual picture of memory). Therefore, it should be impossible (barring bugs) for one application to access the memory used by another application.

Presumably these memory testing programs actually work and aren't lying to me, so assuming it can really read and write all of the memory in the system to test, how is this not a security problem? Not to mention the problem of a Windows application testing the memory it itself is using to run.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Decent memory test software, like MemTest86, boots from (for example) a USB stick... Thus it has access to the entire memory. https://www.memtest86.com/ & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86 What is the name of the memory test software you use?

Comment: My laptop is a Dell, so it was a Dell product called "Support Assist".  It was run from this page: https://www.dell.com/support/diagnose/en-us/Home/Index/Memory

Answer (score 0):

> [...]it should be impossible (barring bugs) for one application to
> access the memory used by another application.

True, *unless the application has the required privileges/permissions*. On most systems, the memory access restrictions can be circumvented with special permissions, as there are some legitimate uses for accessing restricted memory, such as debugging.
On MS Windows specifically, there are, for example, the functions `ReadProcessMemory()` and `WriteProcessMemory()` to do this. However, they require special privileges to work (see e.g. [How do I elevate permissions to access memory in a memory editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211120/how-do-i-elevate-permissions-to-access-memory-in-a-memory-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) for details).

So the service presumably runs with administrator or similar permissions.

> so assuming it can really read and write all of the
> memory in the system to test, how is this not a security problem

If the service has the appropriate permissions to read all memory, then this is not a security problem from the point of view of the OS - the service was authorized when it was installed (by you or the manufacturer). It may still be  a security problem in practice, if the service has security holes (such as a remote code execution vulnerability), but that depends on the service (as with any service running with elevated permissions).

> Presumably these memory testing programs actually work and aren't
> lying to me,

That is not a given - software vendors do bend the truth sometimes, just like anyone else. It seems questionable to me that a service should be able to test memory on a running system, independent of any permissions problems - how can the service test memory that is in use, without interfering with other software? Maybe they did pull that off, or maybe the service only tests memory that is currently not in use, or only tests reads... impossible to know without analyzing it.

As pointed out in comments, the common memory testing programs, such as the BIOS memory check or [Memtest86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86), run right after booting, without loading an operating system, precisely so they get full and exclusive access to memory and CPU.